# Computing Reciprocal Gamma

Tags: cv.complex-variables, special-functions

Reciprocal Gamma $1/\Gamma(z)$ is an entire function and so it has a convergent Taylor series expansion which was given in its wikipedia article.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reciprocal_gamma_function

The problem is there is no citation for it so I want to ask where I can find a proof/derivation of its power series expansion?

Comment: It follows easily from the expansion for $\ln\Gamma$ which in turn is immediately derived from the infinite product for $\Gamma$, as explained in several references at the end of the Wikipedia article.

Answer (score 2):

A good derivation of the Gamma function and it's equivalences is Rainville's [Special Functions](http://books.google.com/books/about/Special_functions.html?id=IO5QAAAAMAAJ) book, see Chapter 2. In there Rainville establishes the equivalent forms of the Gamma functions and relates them to other functions as well. We should also point out that,

$$\frac{1}{\Gamma(z)} = z + \gamma z^2 + \left(\frac{\gamma^2}{2} - \frac{\pi^2}{12}\right)z^3 + \cdots,$$

is as much of the Taylor series as is known, since closed forms of $\zeta(n)$ are only known for he even integers $n$. See [here](http://oeis.org/wiki/Reciprocal_Gamma_function) for a recursive formula for the coefficients of the Gamma function's reciprocal.